# How to use HTTP() class in web2py module

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I'm using a function in a web2py module which should raise an HTTP exception. For most functions (e.g. `T`) I do

```
from gluon import current
def f(x):
    return current.T(x)
```

But I can't do e.g. `raise current.HTTP(...)`: I get

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'HTTP'
```

So is there any way to use HTTP() in a web2py module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is probably just to import `HTTP` in the module:

```
from gluon.http import HTTP

def f(x):
    raise HTTP(200, 'Hello')
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly add the `HTTP` object to the `current` object. In a model file or in the relevant controller:

```
current.HTTP = HTTP
```

Then you will be able to access `current.HTTP` in any module where you import `current`.

Finally, the entire web2py global environment is available via the `current.globalenv` dictionary, so in any module where you import `current`, you can do:

```
raise current.globalenv['HTTP'](200, 'Hello')
```

web2py only adds the `request`, `response`, `session`, `cache`, and `T` objects directly to `current`, so if you want to access any other objects from the global environment, you must either add them explicitly or use `current.globalenv`.